# What keyboard shortcuts are available in Xfce4?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xfce, shortcuts

Note this is all apropos of Xubuntu, in spite of a mention of Mint Xfce.  I actually use 3 OS types, and all three have this issue in one form or another.

I'm looking at Xfce4 documentation [here](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-settings/keyboard) of the Settings->Keyboard app, and I'm a bit puzzled about the keyboard shortcuts, even the ones in the illustration.  Things like <kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> are clear enough once I understand that the <kbd>Super</kbd> key bears an MS Windows logo on my keyboard.  But what are the ones that look like plain text:

```
Mail
WWW
Display
Print
```

and looking on my own machine running Xfce Linux Mint

```
Messenger
Calculator
Home Page
Music
```

Are there keyboards with keys bearing such names, or is something else going on?

Comment: Only Ubuntu and [official flavors of Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Linux Mint forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Linux Mint so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux* found in the on-topic link)

Comment: FYI:  the current HP keyboard I'm using has keys for "*Email*", "*Internet*" and more ... ie. *close* variations of what you're looking for but you're off-topic here with your OS, and your software stack includes an extra layer that Ubuntu has no need for (*runtime adjustments* as Linux Mint *devs* don't have upload privileges to Ubuntu repositories they rely on to alter packages so make changes at runtime)

Comment: Sorry about mentioning Mint.  I get the same sort of thing in Xubuntu, including most of the same names (including Print, Messenger, Explorer, Mail, WWW, Music, Calculator) .  I only put in the reference to OS when I realized I'd gone to the wrong console when filling in the examples.  I run both temporarily.

Comment: Your question mentions *nothing* on-topic (as written) for this site, as the only OS mentioned is an off-topic one for this site.  Please refer to first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there keyboards with keys bearing such names?

Yes. Normally they have icons on them, instead of names.

Sometimes those are separate keys, and sometimes they're combined with <kbd>F1..12</kbd>. In the latter case you have to press <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>F1-12</kbd> to trigger such shortcut.